# How to understand the coalesced access in this CUDA matrix copy code?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, cuda

```cpp
__global__ void Matrixcopy(float *odata, const float *idata)
{
  // threadblock size = (TILE_DIM, BLOCK_ROWS) = (32, 8)
  // each block copies a 32 * 32 tile
  int x = blockIdx.x * TILE_DIM + threadIdx.x;
  int y = blockIdx.y * TILE_DIM + threadIdx.y;
  int width = gridDim.x * TILE_DIM;

  for (int j = 0; j < TILE_DIM; j+= BLOCK_ROWS)
    odata[(y+j)*width + x] = idata[(y+j)*width + x];
}
```

I'm quite confused about the concept of coalesced access for the multi-dim arrays. The definition of the coalesced global memory access is

> Sequential memory access is adjacent

according to the literature [Learn CUDA Programming](https://www.packtpub.com/product/learn-cuda-programming/9781788996242).
For 1-dim arrays, It's easy to understand the threads are indexed as `threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x`, which could easily be mapped to the real 1-dim array: the adjacent threads within a warp access the adjacent physical address of the 1-dim array.

Yet for 2-dim array or a matrix and a 2-dim threadblock like the code above, I'm not sure if I understand it correctly: The adjacent threads within a warp are located in the same row, i.e. same y value, different x values. If y = 0, the contiguous threads are x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6...], and they access contiguous address [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6...] if j = 0. So this code is with coalesced access. Am I correctly understood? And this is just a simple cuda code, if we have a complex cuda kernel, how can we quickly determine whether an access is coalesced or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So this code is with coalesced access. Am I correctly understood?

Yes, pretty much.  I would have said the threads are x = [**0**, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6...], and they access contiguous addresses [**0**, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6...] but basically we are in agreement.

> if we have a complex cuda kernel, how can we quickly determine whether an access is coalesced or not?

You can look at any index construction and use the following test:  If the `threadIdx.x` variable is included in the index as an additive factor, and it has no multiplicative factors on it, then the access will coalesce in typical usage (where you have square-ish threadblocks).  Any index that can be expressed as:

```
idx = f + threadIdx.x
```

where `f` is arbitrary, but does not include `threadIdx.x` will result in coalesced access.  Adjacent threads "in x" will access adjacent locations in memory.  For "non-square-ish" threadblocks, you can develop a similar rule with `threadIdx.y`.  For example, a threadblock of dimensions (1,32) will require that `threadIdx.y` be included as an additive-only factor.